# howt to get Parent Value from firebase java

Tags: java, firebase

I'm currently new to Firebase.

I put a key in-->> user->answer->**key**->true
and then I used this :

```
Firebase re = New Firebase(blabla..user->answer);

refLoadId_Question_Question.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            System.out.println("Id_question1: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
            System.out.println("Id_question1: " + dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString());
            list_id_question.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I receive : Id_question1: {-Ja3RTtq5DMGIdVF9-pC=true} in dataSnapsho.getValue();

my Question is it Possible to get key Value from Object type in java? I want to get this value :**-Ja3RTtq5DMGIdVF9-pC**

anyone Please help? 
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Currently used this code to get the ID.

but I didn't try it if the ID question is more than one

```
if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
        Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        String ID_Question = newPost.keySet().toString().replace("[", "");
        ID_Question = ID_Question.replace("]", "");
        System.out.println("Id_question1: " + ID_Question);
        list_id_question.add(ID_Question);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the children:

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey());
}
```

Alternatively you could also listen for children, instead of the entire answer object:

```
refLoadId_Question_Question.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot childSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey());
    }
}
```

The latter is going to be simpler when you start to deal with data **synchronization** instead of just just pulling down the initial data.

Say you have two people using your application:

1. the first user is viewing a question and (for the sake of this example) its two answers
2. the second user is providing a third answer to the same question

Initially the first user will download the question and the two answers. Then when the second user provide a third answer, your initial code will (likely) re-download all three answers. The second example will only be called for the new answer.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer i'm going to try it, but now i'm going to find the bugs first from my app. i'll tell you soon.